# Server Exception: Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object

Tags: web-part

I am trying to get the Web Part gallery using the code given below:

```
var clientcontext = Admin.GetAuthenticatedClientContext(siteUrl);
var uri = new Uri(pageUrl);
var file = clientcontext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(uri.LocalPath);
ClientOM.List testcoll = clientcontext.Web.GetCatalog((int)ClientOM.ListTemplateType.WebPartCatalog);
ClientOM.CamlQuery query = ClientOM.CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();

ClientOM.ListItemCollection test = testcoll.GetItems(query);
clientcontext.Load(test);
clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But it keeps throwing exception,

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: Cannot invoke method or
>   retrieve property from null object.
>
> Object returned by the following call stack is null.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to list all the web parts from the gallery using client object model? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably this error occurs since you are trying to retrieve web parts gallery **not** on the root site.

Replace the line:

```
ClientOM.List testcoll = clientcontext.Web.GetCatalog((int)ClientOM.ListTemplateType.WebPartCatalog);
```

with this one:

```
ClientOM.List testcoll = clientcontext.Site.RootWeb.GetCatalog((int)ClientOM.ListTemplateType.WebPartCatalog);
```

### How to retrieve Web Parts gallery using CSOM

```
public static ListItemCollection GetWebParts(ClientContext ctx)
{
        List list = ctx.Site.RootWeb.GetCatalog((int)ListTemplateType.WebPartCatalog);
        CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
        ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
        ctx.Load(items);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        return items;
}
```